# Why Xcode is launching a simulator when performing a test from a Logic Unit Test target?

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest

When I am performing a test from a target defined as logic unit test in Xcode a simulator is launching. Usually a suite of test, will finish with a result success / failure before a simulator will finish launching.

Why a logic test unit target when performing a tests launch a simulator?

Comment: The unit test is a bundle injected into your app. To run the test we must run the app. The simulator is where we run it.

Comment: @matt after reading following document I understood that a logic unit test doesn't depend on an app bundle https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/02-Setting_Up_Unit_Tests_in_a_Project/setting_up.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002143-CH3-SW6

Comment: That document is way outdated. It says so right in it. There is no longer any distinction between types of unit test. There hasn’t been for many years.

Comment: @matt So, today when using the XCTest framework we have only a Application Unit Test and a Logic Unit Test are no more accessible?

Comment: In effect yes, that’s right.

Comment: @matt so, what happens when I would like to launch a test suite under Linux? I am not sure if a simulator is accessible on Linux platform.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190315/discussion-between-adobels-and-matt).

Comment: I do not know what it would even mean to run an app project on Linux. You have to be in Xcode or nowhere, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your unit test, while not needing a GUI, is still an iOS simulator bundle, not a macOS bundle. Therefore it needs to run in an iOS simulator environment.